# Find line in file, grab substring of that line and replace with another string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

I kinda coded myself into a corner. Not sure if my design is correct. But I'm committed (for now) to this design. Basically I am looping through a ton of files. For each of those files, I'm doing another loop and looking for particular strings. If I find them, I store them into an array. Then with that array, I am looping again and want to do some type of sed and replace. Here is my code at the moment...

```
for ruleset in "${rulesets[@]}"
do
    for dml in "${dmls[@]}"
    do
        grep ${dml} ${ruleset}
        RC=${?}
        if [ $RC -eq 0 ]; then
            my_array=()
            while IFS= read -r line
            do
                my_array+=( "$line" )
            done < <( grep ${dml} ${ruleset} )
            for string in "${my_array[@]}"
            do
                ********THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP*********
            done
        fi
    done
done
```

So let's brute force this. I have a file which is $ruleset and I grep for this string which is $dml "cems_wf_attr.dml" which returns a few results and I store those results into an array. That result is :

```
<required_dml file_name="$AI_DATA_MOUNT/sandbox/waterfall_ces/curr/shared/dml/strat_output/cems_wf_attr.dml"></required_dml>
<extdataset>$AI_DATA_MOUNT/sandbox/waterfall_ces/curr/shared/dml/strat_output/cems_wf_attr.dml</extdataset>
<required_dml file_name="$AI_DATA_MOUNT/sandbox/waterfall_ces/curr/shared/dml/strat_output/cems_wf_attr.dml"></required_dml>
<extdataset>$AI_DATA_MOUNT/sandbox/waterfall_ces/curr/shared/dml/strat_output/cems_wf_attr.dml</extdataset>
```

Awesome!! Pretty straight forward. This is what I now need to do. I need to replace those entries in the $ruleset file. So for those 4 lines (which are stored in my array) i need to replace there values. Values could be two possibles "types" of values. There's a...

```
required_dml file_name
```

and there's a...

```
extdataset
```

Basically I need to replace the directory of this file. So depending on the $dml string value it will always be a particular string replacement. So for this string which is "cems_wf_attr.dml" it will ALWAYS be replaced with "$SHARED_DML/strat_output/cems_wf_attr.dml"

Because it will always be replaced as that, my idea was to have a file that has all of my possible final values. Because the filenames are the same as the original values I will just grep this file with the $dml variable to get the final value and now I can use that to replace. I'm using a file because it's easy and I don't know how to do like a dictionary of some sort in ksh. Anyway, I just need help now with the sed and or awk command to do this replace and how that would look. Thanks!!

Comment: **"I'm suing a file"**, this country is so litigious! good luck at court :)

Comment: Are you looking for regular expressions or literal strings?

Comment: regular expression if possible

Comment: do you know the value to modify ? I mean, do you know beforehand that this cems_wf_attr_dml file is/was in "$AI_DATA_MOUNT/sandbox/waterfall_ces/curr/shared/dml/strat_output/" ? or you only know where the files are/will be after the modification ?

Comment: I only know after yes based on the file name. but that file name could sit in a handful of directories

Comment: You 4 lines found by `grep`. Can you add 4 lines how they should look like? Everything above those 4 lines might not be relevant.